# Anaconda can't install python - permission denied

Tags: python, anaconda

I'm trying to isntall the enviroments from the pyviz tutorial as described in http://pyviz.org/tutorial/00_Setup.html.

But when I run 
`conda create -n pyviz-tutorial python=3.6`

It tells me:

```
ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(507): An error occurred while installing package 'defaults::python-3.6.7-h9f7ef89_2'.
PermissionError(13, 'Permission denied')
```

I tried running the anaconda prompt as administrator and changing permissions on the anaconda folder but both failed to resolve the issue.

How can I solve this?

EDIT: This is on windows

Thanks.

Comment: I believe I got this error when I way trying to install in C:\ProgramFiles. That's why I always install in C:\Anaconda2 where I have all the rights I need to install packages via `conda install`

Comment: My c: drive is nearly full so i have anaconda installed on E: drive. That shouldn't make a difference I think? When I try to install python with anaconda it tells me "# All requested packages already installed."

Comment: No, it should be fine on whatever drive you put it, as long as you have all rights. With Anaconda you don't need to install python, it's already there

Answer (score 0):

Try to start the conda terminal with administrator rights. In my experience this helps on Win8 (and is not necessary on Win10).